# The tiny difference of pronunciation in german suffix

Tags: pronunciation

I am always puzzled about the pronunciation of the german suffix '-e' and '-er'.

What I want so say is, that I could not hear the difference between them clearly if it were not for the article that defines the gender of the noun. 
I also can't pronounce them as clearly as I should to show their obvious difference.

For instance:

> ein Deutsch**er** \ ein**e** Deutsch**e**, 
>   ein schön**er**... \ ein**e** schön**e**...

I guess that native German speakers don't take it as a big problem, because, as I said, the gender and the function of the noun in the sentence tell everything I want to express.

Is that right??

Comment: I am not completely sure what the question is.

Comment: My guess is that your problem arises because German has two distinct central vowels: The ["normal" Schwa](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) and the [a-Schwa](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_offener_Zentralvokal), whereas in English the two are allophones.

Comment: The distinction between -e and -er is very hard for most English speakers, and often neglected in German classes for nonnative speakers. It also lies at the heart of the debate about the correct pronunciation of Porsche.

Answer (score 1):

One word of consolation up front: Even natives sometimes have to ask …

Your observation is correct. The differences in pronunciation are rather subtle, especially if the speaker doesn't enunciate clearly.

But you have more than just articles to help you: Consider adjectives, whose form must match the noun, too. Sometimes it's just hearing it *twice* that does the trick:

> schön**er** Deutsch**er** vs. schön**e** Deutsch**e**.

And there's always the context …

Comment: and on the region... in Berlin for example it will be incredibly clear. "er" is "ah" and "e" is "e"